# Is there is a way to insert macro to worksheet from Excel Addin?

Tags: excel, vba, office-js, worksheet, javascript-api-for-office

I searched documentation [Office Excel API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office), but cannot find any mentions at all, how it can be implemented.

The Problem:

Luck of API functionality or some sort of bugs can be solved easily by VBA macros.

But, for doing that, we have only two possibilities:

1. Insert macro manually into sheet, which will catch some event on sheet, and JS from addin will trigger that event (this solution came from very old forum (if I will find the link, I will insert it here)).
2. Insert macro by JS code to sheet (context.workbook.worksheet?) during addin runtime, and even it cannot be executed by addin, but in this case the end user do not need to manage macro at all - we can make process of macro running more smooth with the same logic (JS inserts macro into sheet, change some value in sheet and then it triggers some macro, and after that (for example after some timeout in JS or just by another event in JS we can easily delete the whole sheet with this macro)).

So the question is, is it possible somehow make something similar to solution 2 using the Excel API? 
(some sort of function to insert/delete VBA code from addin)

I will appreciate any help!

**Example to clarify problem**

I'm using the JavaScript API, but unfortunately the API doesn't cover full functionally (I hope yet) which is already existed in VBA. Let me explain it on a simple example:

Imagine a task:

1. We need to copy some information from sheet 1 in workbook 1
2. then we need to create a book and just put the values in new workbook 2
3. then we need to suggest to user where it(new workbook 2) needs to be saved.
4. then we need save and close workbook 2.

VBA resolves the problem easily, but in case JS API - there is no full solution of this problem (without third-party applications).

You can compare API JS and VBA by follwoing links below:

[Workbooks JS API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks)

[Workbooks VBA API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook)

So what I want to do - is to write actual VBA macro in JavaScript and insert this VBA macro into sheet to make the macro executable.

**How to make macro executable from some value change on sheet?**

I found out that, if you call `select` method directly applying to cell and catch selection change using `Worksheet_SelectionChange` in VBA - it perfectly worked.

Unfortunately direct set values to cell doesn't trigger VBA `Worksheet_change`

**Why am I using JS API**

Currently I already have a VBA project for similar tasks, but as the project grow and evolve - some features here, some features here, I saw that addins - is the best solution to resolve key problems - its easier to maintain, manage, develop, push updates, install, and it just look better - because an addin is just one simple website

**Update 2019/09/20 - Possible Workaround**

First of all, great thanks to @DecimalTurn, who made this workaround possible. See [his original answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58002240/9908821)

I a little bit modify it and added additional JS script and VBA script to make this solution complete. So:

1. The following VBA macros needs to be inserted BEFORE you will make any actions from JS to `ThisWorkbook` module:

1.1. VBA macro which will handle all VBA code which we will transfer

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error GoTo endline
    Const SheetName As String = "_WorksheetSheetWorker"

    CheckIfVBAAccessIsOn

    If InStr(1, Sh.name, SheetName, vbBinaryCompare) >= 0 Then
        If Sh.Range("$A$1") <> vbNullString Then

            Const ModuleName As String = "m_TempMacroJS"

            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
            'We will take MacroName from sheet which we added from JS
            Dim MacroName As String
            MacroName = ws.Range("A2").Value2

            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
            Dim pathToMacroBas As String

            'Export the content of the cell to a .bas file
            pathToMacroBas = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ModuleName & ".bas"
            Open pathToMacroBas For Output As #1
            Print #1, "Attribute VB_Name = """ & ModuleName & """ " & vbNewLine & ws.Range("A1").Value2
            Close #1

            'Declare VBProject Object
            Dim vbaProject As VBProject
            Set vbaProject = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

            'Delete pre-existing module with the same name
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Load the code as a new Module
                vbaProject.VBComponents.Import ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ModuleName & ".bas"
                Dim vbaModule As VBIDE.VBComponent
                Set vbaModule = vbaProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)

                'Run the code and transfer working sheet to macro
                'You can use this worksheet to transfer values to macro as JSON
                Application.Run ModuleName & "." & MacroName, ws

                'Cleanup
                ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbaModule 
                'Optional
                Kill pathToMacroBas
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
        Exit Sub
      endline:
      End Sub
```

1.2 VBA macro which will programmatic way enable `Trust access to the VBA project object model`. Please note: You will still need also enable `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3`

I found the solution on link [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cristib/2012/02/29/vba-how-to-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros/) and a little modify it - the macro creates VBScript and enable `Trust access to the VBA project object model` directly in register. The problem which I cannot handle yet - is the delay. The time of delay is needed to save and close existed workbook.

```
Sub CheckIfVBAAccessIsOn()

    '[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Office/10.0/Excel/Security]
    '"AccessVBOM"=dword:00000001

    Dim strRegPath As String
    strRegPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"

    If TestIfKeyExists(strRegPath) = False Then
      MsgBox "A change has been introduced into your registry configuration. All changes will be saved. Please reopen book."
      WriteVBS
      ThisWorkbook.Save
      Application.Quit
    End If

  End Sub

  Function TestIfKeyExists(ByVal path As String)
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim RegValue As Boolean
    RegValue = WshShell.RegRead(path)
    If RegValue = True Then
      TestIfKeyExists = True
    Else
      TestIfKeyExists = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
  End Function

  Sub WriteVBS()
    Dim objFile         As Object
    Dim objFSO          As Object
    Dim codePath        As String
    codePath = Me.path & "\reg_setting.vbs"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(codePath, 2, True)

    objFile.WriteLine (" On Error Resume Next")
    objFile.WriteLine ("")
    objFile.WriteLine ("Dim WshShell")
    objFile.WriteLine ("Set WshShell = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")")
    objFile.WriteLine ("")
    objFile.WriteLine ("MsgBox ""Please wait until Excel will closes! Click OK to complete the setup process.""")
    objFile.WriteLine ("")
    objFile.WriteLine ("Dim strRegPath")
    objFile.WriteLine ("Dim Application_Version")
    objFile.WriteLine ("Application_Version = """ & Application.Version & """")
    objFile.WriteLine ("strRegPath = ""HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\"" & Application_Version & ""\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM""")
    objFile.WriteLine ("WScript.echo strRegPath")
    objFile.WriteLine ("WshShell.RegWrite strRegPath, 1, ""REG_DWORD""")
    objFile.WriteLine ("")
    objFile.WriteLine ("If Err.Code <> o Then")
    objFile.WriteLine ("   MsgBox ""Error"" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Err.Source & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Err.Message")
    objFile.WriteLine ("End If")
    objFile.WriteLine ("")
    objFile.WriteLine ("WScript.Quit")

    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    'run the VBscript code
    ' > The macro will fail to execute the VB script if you use a
    '   [codepath] which contains blanks!
    '
    ' > To fix this issue, we add a pair of double quotes (" ") around
    '   [codepath];
    Shell "cscript " & Chr(34) & codePath & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus

  End Sub
```

2. Second part I wrote based on @DecimalTurn suggestion to create sheet in JS and then catch this event from VBA and wrapped up whole code in one JS instance:

```
    const VBAWorker = function(){
      /* This is a name of tempurary sheet to execute macro */
      this._executedMacroName = "JSSubRunner"
      /* This is the name of sheet worker*/
      this._WorksheetSheetWorkerName = "_WorksheetSheetWorker"
      /* These options can be applied to already existed sheet*/
      this._worksheetExistenceDecisionOptions = {
        replaceSheet : "replaceSheet",
        findNewAvailableName : "findNewAvailableName"
      }
    }


    /**
     * Function to run macro using sheet worker
     * @param {String} VBAMacro is a code which will be executed
     * @param {String} transferredValues (optional) are a values which we need 
     * to place into executable macro
     * @param {String} worksheetDesicion (optional) is a desicion which we will if the worker worksheet exists
     * default = "replaceSheet", possible = "findNewAvailableName"
     */
    VBAWorker.prototype.run= async function(VBAMacro, transferredValues = "", worksheetDesicion = "replaceSheet"){
      const defaultWorksheetName = this._WorksheetSheetWorkerName
      let worksheetName = defaultWorksheetName
      const preparedVBAMacro = this._changeMacroName(VBAMacro) 
      await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        /* First we need to check out existence of sheet worker*/
        let sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
        sheets.load("items/name");

        await context.sync()
        /**
         *  In this case we will deside what to do 
         *  if we will find sheet with the same name
         * */ 
        const isSheetExists = this._checkWorksheetExistence(sheets)
        const decisionOptions = this._worksheetExistenceDecisionOptions
        if (isSheetExists){
          switch (worksheetDesicion){
            case decisionOptions.replaceSheet:
              let sheetToReplace = sheets.getItem(worksheetName)
              sheetToReplace.delete()
              await context.sync()
            break;
            case decisionOptions.findNewAvailableName:
              worksheetName = this._changeNameOfWorkerWorksheet(sheets) 
            break;
          }
        } else {
          /* we will keep worksheetName as default */
        }

        let sheet = sheets.add(worksheetName);
        let macroExeCell = sheet.getCell(0,0)
        let macroNameCell = sheet.getCell(1,0)
        let macroValuesCell = sheet.getCell(0,1)
        macroExeCell.values = preparedVBAMacro
        macroNameCell.values = this._executedMacroName
        let preparedValues = []
        const limit = 32700 
        const lengthOfString = transferredValues.length
        // console.log(transferredValues.length)
        // console.log(transferredValues.length / limit)
          if (lengthOfString > limit) {
            try {
              let done = false

              /* during cell lenght limit we will slice string to many*/
              let lastStep = false
              let current = limit
              let oldcurrent = 0

              do {
                let end = current
                let start = oldcurrent
                /* Check that the next simbol not equals to "=" */
                if(transferredValues.slice(end, end + 1) == "="){
                  current += 1
                  end = current
                }

                if (lengthOfString < start ){
                  start = lengthOfString
                }  
                if (lengthOfString < end){
                  end = lengthOfString
                  lastStep = true
                }

                preparedValues.push(transferredValues.slice(start, end))

                if (lastStep){
                  done = true
                } else {
                  oldcurrent = current
                  current += limit
                }
              } while (done == false)
              /* Write values to sheet*/
              await preparedValues.forEach(async (el, i)=>{
                macroValuesCell = sheet.getCell(0 + i,1)
                macroValuesCell.values = [[el]]
              })
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
          } else {
            /* If string.length is less then limit we just put it directly to one cell*/
            macroValuesCell.values = [[transferredValues]]
          }
        return await context.sync();
      });
    }

    /**
     * Function to search available name of sheet and return it
     * @param {Array} sheets - worksheet items with 
     * returns suggestedName (string)
     */
    VBAWorker.prototype._changeNameOfWorkerWorksheet = function(sheets){
      try {
        let suggestCounter = 0
        let suggestedName; 
        let suggestedNameIsFree = false;
        let worksheetName = this._WorksheetSheetWorkerName
        do {
          suggestedName = worksheetName + suggestCounter 
          suggestCounter = suggestCounter +1
          suggestedNameIsFree = !this._checkWorksheetExistence(sheets)
        } while (suggestedNameIsFree = false);
        return suggestedName

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }

    /**
     * Function to check worksheet name existence
     * @param {Array} sheets - worksheet items with names
     * returns true or false
     */
    VBAWorker.prototype._checkWorksheetExistence = function(sheets){
      let isSheetExists = false
      sheets.items.forEach(el=>{
        if(el.name == this._WorksheetSheetWorkerName){
          isSheetExists = true
          return;
        }
      }) 
      return isSheetExists
    }

    /**
     * Function to change name of running macro
     * @param {String} VBAMacro is a string that contains executed macro
     * The name of running sub will be changed to "_JSSubRunner"
     */
    VBAWorker.prototype._changeMacroName =function(VBAMacro){
      const regex = /(Sub\s+)(.*)([(])/i
      const renamedVBAMacro = VBAMacro.replace(regex, `Sub ${this._executedMacroName} (`)
      return renamedVBAMacro
    }

    export default VBAWorker
```

*How it can be used?*

You can used it as simple instance calling the VBAWorker that way:

```
  const VBAWorkerInst = new VBAWorker()
  await VBAWorkerInst.run(
    "your VBA code goes here",
    "your values in string (JSON for example) goes here",
    "optional option:) - a name of decision what we need to do, if sheet already existed"
  )
```

Your macro can have any name, because this VBAWorker will take care of it and will change that name to unify it.

*Please note:* because Excel is asynchronous we need to wait until all promises will resolved! So the code above must be wrapped in asynchronous function or you can catch the promise callback.

I'm not tested yet, but I think it's possible to run more than one macro, and we can use the same strategy as for values to write more usefull code.

So that's all in this moment:) Really hope that with time there will be simpler solution..

Comment: Didn't actually understood exactly the question but I think you are looking for this https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html

Comment: I'm confused -- do you want to write the actual macro in VBA, or using the [Javascript API for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office)?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I updated my question, please see Update 1 paragraph

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to access the VBProject that contains the VBA code from the Excel Javascript API, but there could be a workaround. 
Are you allowed to have some other VBA code (not the macro you want to run) already sitting inside the workbook before running your code from the JS API?

Comment: @DecimalTurn Yes, its allowed.

Comment: So now the question is, why do you need JS at all? Why not do this purely using VBA? (As a side note, when editing your question, you don't need to present the history of your question -- you don't need a section **Update 1**, **Update 2** etc. -- because StackOverflow automatically keeps track of any edits you made. Instead, you should strive to make your question as clear as possible.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz currently I already have a VBA project for similar tasks, but as a project grow and evolve - some features here, some features here, I saw that addins - is the best solution to resolve key problems - its easier to maintain, manage, develop, push updates, install, and it just look better - because an addin is just one simple website - but certainly, as I wrote before, it lucks some functions. Updates - noted, thank you for your advise

Comment: I think there is a possible workaround using an event procedure, but I ran into problems when trying to trigger a VBA event from Office-JS, so I asked this more [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001786/can-office-js-trigger-a-vba-workbook-or-worksheet-event-procedure). If that question has an answer, I should be able to provide a complete answer to your question.

Comment: Put the content into a specific cell, and then select it via the js API - your VBA SelectionChange event handler can monitor for that selection and then do whatever it needs to with the cell content.  This kind of sucks though, and it's likley to lead to a mess.  You could more easily make a self-updating VBA add-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Potential Workaround

As a disclaimer, this method could introduce some vulnerability in the Excel file you are using, so you have to be careful with this by using unique names for your macro, module and sheet name to make sure no add-in will run VBA code without your consent.

The idea would be to create a new worksheet and write the code of your macro into a cell inside that worksheet (Let's say cell A1). Then, there would be a VBA Event procedure already present in the `ThisWorkbook` module that will do the heavy lifting to make your macro run.

Assuming that the `Trust access to the VBA project object model` was enabled and that you've added the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` Library to your workbook, you could have the following VBA event procedure inside `ThisWorkbook`:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "NewSheet" Then
        If Sh.Range("$A$1") <> vbNullString Then
            
            Const ModuleName As String = "MacroJs"
            Const MacroName As String = "YourMacroName"
            Const SheetName As String = "NewSheet"
            
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
            
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
            
            'Export the content of the cell to a .bas file
            Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ModuleName & ".bas" For Output As #1
            Print #1, "Attribute VB_Name = """ & ModuleName & """ " & vbNewLine & ws.Range("A1").Value2
            Close #1
            
            'Declare VBProject Object
            Dim vbaProject As VBProject
            Set vbaProject = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
            
            'Delete pre-existing module with the same name
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            'Load the code as a new Module
            vbaProject.VBComponents.Import ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ModuleName & ".bas"
            Dim vbaModule As VBIDE.VBComponent
            Set vbaModule = vbaProject.VBComponents(ModuleName)
            
            'Run the code
            Application.Run ModuleName & "." & MacroName
            
            'Cleanup
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove vbaModule 'Optional
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This procedure would be triggered by the creation of a sheet by your Office-JS code.

Note that I would also advise to add some error handling to make sure that the cleanup section will run in case there is a run-time error while running the code.

And then your JavaScript code would look like this:

```
var sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
var sheet = sheets.add("NewSheet");
sheet.getRange("A1").values = [['sub YourMacroName() \n Msgbox "Test" \n End sub']];
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I used your workaround to make complete solution and pick it in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this capability does not existing the Office.js API today. I would post a require on the Office Add-ins User Voice site at: https://officespdev.uservoice.com.  thank you.